# How exactly do p2p networks connect?

Tags: sockets, p2p

If I establish a connection with a friend on Skype, the audio and video data does not go through Microsoft but directly. I also have a p2p client X that does a similar thing.  I do not fully understand how this happens internally. How does a machine establish the connection with the other if there is no direct identifier such as a public IP address? Multiple computers in the same network can each do p2p or Skype calls at the same time.

I have been wondering about this for a week because I want to connect two Nodes with each other (like a socket server/client).  Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If two clients want to connect, but neither knows the address of the other, some sort of intermediary that they both know has to be in place to help set up the connection. They both contact the intermediary with the desire to connect, the intermediary tells them both what the others direct address is, and the connection can be set up directly.

Sometimes (read: always) one or both machines share a public IP with others behind NAT, and NAT traversal techniques are needed to establish end-to-end connectivity, usually some form of ICE or SIP.

Comment: How I determine this 'direct address' in lets say simple socket connection?

Comment: @JochemStoel Who is "I" in this scenario? The intermediary? That's just the remote address of the one making the request. The intermediary will have to keep track of state on the application layer.